# Scrolling with keys on specific website

Tags: jquery, html, web, scroll

Can somebody please tell why, if I visit this website http://robo.sc-nm.si/ I can't scroll
with cursor keys or pageup/pagedown until I click on the website?

Is there maybe some script code waiting for key press or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with trial and error, I went deleting every single line of code.

I found it in load.css, the two commented lines below. If I delete position attribute I loose
the horizontal slider, so I have to delete overflow also..

That's what I get with using templates =)

```
#siteWrapper {
  /* position:absolute; z-index:1; */
  /* overflow:auto; */  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this web site has an PopUp advertisement. If you open it on Internet Explorer you can see it.

If you are using Chrome, when you click on the page, javascript wants to open a popup window to show ads. But chrome blocks it. That's why you can't scroll untill you click on the screen.

Your click makes the "invisible div" disappear. That's how you can scrool after clicking.